# Curious behaviour of vertical space in one and two column document

Tags: spacing, multicol

When I use the first code (in a two-column document) the vertical space between the text and the `gather` environment is small. When I use the starred version or a one-column document then the space becomes bigger. Why is that happening. Can\Should I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{multicols}{2}
Hello there
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&x+y=0\\
&y=0
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&z+x=0\\
&z=0
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When I use `\begin{multicols*}{2}`:

[image]

And when I don't use multiple columns:

[image]